# Serving Angular content and HTML+CSS content from Node/Express backend

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I have one Node/Express server where I am serving both an Angular application and some static HTML. I serve the Angular application out of dist/angular and the static content out of static-content:

```
// This has to be in this order or else it doesnt work for some reason
app.use(express.static('./static-content'));
app.use(express.static('./dist/angular'));

app.use(parser.json());

// some other routes ...

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/static-content/index.html'));
});

app.get('/app/*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/dist/angular/index.html'));
});

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  let httpsHost = req.headers.host.replace('8081', '8443');
  res.writeHead(301, {"Location": "https://" + httpsHost + req.url});
  res.end();
}).listen(8081);

https.createServer(httpsOptions, app).listen(8443)
```

If you change the order of the express.static at the top, it will not serve the static-content so I am wondering if this is the correct way to serve both an Angular application and HTML+CSS content out of one Node/Express server?